# Does there exist radiation inside nucleus because of strong forces?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Just like there exist electromagnetic radiation  correspond to electromagnetic field  then does there exist radiation corresponding to strong field inside nucleus.

Comment: The mediator of nucleon-nucleon interactions are mesons. Inside a nucleus they are virtual, but they can become real as short lived resonances in scattering experiments.

Comment: Yes, quarks exchange gluons between them. Quarks can radiate gluons.  [In theoretical particle physics, the gluon field is a four vector field characterizing the propagation of gluons in the strong interaction between quarks. It plays the same role in quantum chromodynamics as the electromagnetic four-potential in quantum electrodynamics - the gluon field constructs the gluon field strength tensor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon_field)

Comment: As mentioned above, the strong interactions betweeen quarks inside protons and neutrons are mediated by massless gluons while the residual strong interactions between protons and neutrons inside a nucleus are mediated by massive pions (mesons) that consist of a quark and anti-quark. The electromagnetic equivalent of residual interactions is the attraction of neutral atoms to form a molecule. While atoms are neutral, electrons of one still attract to the nucleus of the other and vice verse. Unlike photons that can fly free, gluons are confined inside protons and neutrons.

Comment: Adding to the above comments, gluons are confined inside nucleons because they carry a color quantum number.  QCD predicts, however, that color neutral bound states of gluons (called glueballs or gluonium) should exist and could escape from nucleon or nuclear confinement.  Unfortunately, their experimental signature would be very similar to those of mesons so they have not been experimentally identified. You might appreciate this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball